# Unrecognized selector sent to instance error when I click my buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, button, selector

I've spent the day trying to figure out why I'm getting this Error whenever I click on one of my buttons that was generated in Code:

> -[HomeViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102813a00
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeViewController aMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102813a00'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x184e83164 0x1840cc528 0x184e90628 0x18e7fe188 0x184e88b10 0x184d6dccc 0x18e4725cc 0x18e47254c 0x18e45d0f4 0x18e47a368 0x18eacd5e4 0x18eac8b94 0x18eac8678 0x18eac77d4 0x18e46ce5c 0x18e43de7c 0x18ed9330c 0x18ed95898 0x18ed8e7b0 0x184e2b77c 0x184e2b6fc 0x184e2af84 0x184e28b5c 0x184d48c58 0x186bf4f84 0x18e4a15c4 0x100eb5a20 0x18486856c)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I am new to Objective-C and iOS. There's a very good chance I'm missing something simple/basic.

Here is the code that creates the buttons:

```
for (int i =0 ; i < numDevices; i++)
{
    CBPeripheral* periph = devices[i];
    printf("%s%s\n", "Found Devices Name: ", [[periph name] UTF8String] );


    //Create button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:[periph name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 100);

    //set constraints on button
    [button.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = true;
    //[button.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:210].active = true;

    //set image
    UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"App_Background.png"]];
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 100);
    [button addSubview:iv];

    //Add action event to button
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(Test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //add button to stackview
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:button];
}
```

Here is the function that is supposed to be called when a button is clicked:

```
    -(IBAction) Test: (id) sender
{
    //printf("%s%s\n", "Selected Button: ", [[sender currentTitle] UTF8String]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
[button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

This button calls `aMethod:` on `self`, but you have not defined that method! Deleting that line should fix the issue.

Comment: I commented out that line, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I would suggest doing a quick clean (Shift + Command + K) and try again. That is definitely why you're getting that error.

Comment: Also, your `Test:` method doesn't need a `IBAction` return type. That's just for interface builder, which you are not using for this button.

Comment: Oh my god. I was looking at the wrong line. I completely forgot I added that line many hours ago. Thank you so much. An extra pair of eyes is nice to have sometimes.

Comment: Happens to us all :)